# @PostContruct and @PreDestroy are not getting called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

yea so these annotated functions are not getting called, here's the code for the main class

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ){

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanConfig.class);
        Doctor staff = context.getBean(Doctor.class);
        staff.assist();
        staff.setQualification("MBBS");
        System.out.println(staff);

        ((AnnotationConfigApplicationContext) context).close();
    }
}
```

Here's the doctor class

```
package com.example;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Component 
@Scope(scopeName = "prototype") //Define scope like this
public class Doctor implements Staff, BeanNameAware{

    private String qualification; 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Doctor [qualification=" + qualification + "]";
    }

    public void assist(){
        System.out.println("Doctor is assisting");
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String arg0) {
        System.out.println("Set Bean name method is called");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
        System.out.println("Post contruct");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy(){
        System.out.println("Predestroy");
    }

}
```

And here's the bean config class

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com")
public class BeanConfig {
     
}
```

And this is the output

```
D:\Java\Spring\spring-tuts\demo> d: && cd d:\Java\Spring\spring-tuts\demo && cmd /C "D:\Java\jdk\jdk-17.0.4.1\bin\java.exe @C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_352s2qzst60fhnczvuupchjj8.argfile com.example.App "
Set Bean name method is called
Doctor is assisting
Doctor [qualification=MBBS]
```

Like what else am I missing, i'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvR-Oif_nxg) to the T, yet i'm getting different output. The beanNameAware function is working, why aren't the others working?

Tried looking at other people's stackoverflow questions having the same issue, but none of them had answers that worked for me

Comment: check if  javax.annotation-api dependency is added

Comment: yes those are added

Comment: You don't follow it to the T as your package names are already different, you state you are using Spring Boot (where the tutorial starts with plain Spring). You probably also decided to use newer versions of Spring (Boot) as opposed to the tutorial. If you are using Spring 6 (Spring BOot 3) you will need the Jakarta version of those annotations, if you don't make sure you recompile **all** your code and not just change it. The presenter uses an IDE you appear to be using the command line, which doesn't automatically recompile stuff.

Comment: @M.Deinum when i meant following it to the T, I mean the code, variable names can be different, but logic is the same. I've just added the spring-boot tag, for better reach, never have i mentioned I'm specifically using it. Since PostConstruct and PreDestroy are similar for both spring and spring boot, (I know they aren't 100% similar, but enough to get help), since spring boot has more user base than spring. I'm using the same version as him, but could you still extrapolate on the jakarta version thing, just so i can check it out.

Comment: If you aren't using Spring Boot then don't tag it as such, I removed the tag. The postconstruct/predestroy are the same. If you are using the same versions as he is, there is no Jakarta support, so you can ignore it. If you say you follow it to the T you are doing everything exactly the same (and you aren't). As stated looks like you are running from the command line, make sure you recompiled **all classes**.

Comment: Ok so after recompiling, the postcontruct is working, but the predestroy is still not showing up